# Invalid input: SVC-DIROPEN: xdmp:filesystem-directory("D:\Application\xml")

Tags: marklogic

I have some `xml` files in my local system drive and I want to load these `xml` files in remote `Marklogic` server 4.2 which I access by IP address and password. But, I try to upload directly by using `database` or by `xquery` code it show below error so is there any solution without `WebDAV` server to load `xml` files in remote marklogic database?

Error:-

```
Invalid input: SVC-DIROPEN: xdmp:filesystem-directory("D:\Application\xml") -- Directory open error: FindFirstFile 'D:\Application\xml\*': The system cannot find the path specified.

[1.0-ml] SVC-FILOPN: xdmp:document-get("file://D:/Application/xml/ch001s001.xml", <options xmlns="xdmp:document-get"><encoding>UTF-8</encoding><repair>full</repair></options>) -- File open error: open '/Application/xml/ch001s001.xml': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that the mentioned directory exists only on your local machine, and not on the remote server. The xdmp:filesystem-*, as well as functions like xdmp:document-get look on the filesystem relative to the server. So, 'c:\' would point to the c:\ path on the server, not your local machine.

You can use `HTTP` `PUT` or `POST` requests to send your files to MarkLogic, but that requires an XQuery file that is able to take care of such requests. Other, perhaps easier options, involve setting up an `XDBC` server, and using tools like RecordLoader, xmlsh, etc. to push your documents to MarkLogic. You can find these at http://developer.marklogic.com/.

HTH!

PS: what do you have against using `WebDAV`? There are plenty libraries around that would be able to push content into MarkLogic using `WebDAV`. There are even MarkLogic Ant tasks for that.